# Powershell: Capturing Combined output, error output only, sending combined output to console

Tags: powershell, io-redirection, tee

I'm creating a Powershell script to run a bunch of scala scripts (I have reasons for not using a build tool). I'd like to generate output for all these compilations this way:

1. Just the compilation errors in a file
2. Compilation errors and standard output combined in a second file
3. Standard output and compilation errors also go to standard output

I've tried **tee**, **2>>**, and even poked at **-OutVariable** and **-ErrorVariable** (the latter two only seem to work for native Powershell commands?). I suspect **tee** and redirection are the right approach in some combination but after significant searching around I can't seem to find the right forumula.

Here's my current main loop, which is only redirecting errors:

```
foreach($script in $scripts) {
    Write-Host scala $script
    scala -nocompdaemon $script 2>> _testerrors.txt
}
```

The first line is so the person watching the process can see that something is happening (it seems like proper teeing/redirection/etc. would eliminate this, as a side effect).

Thanks for any help/pointers; I'm just a casual user of Powershell.

**Update:**

More hunting around has produced the following:

```
foreach($script in $scripts) {
    Write-Host scala $script
    Write-Output "> scala $script" | Out-File ./_testoutput.txt -append
    scala -nocompdaemon $script 2>&1 | tee -Variable testout
    out-file ./_testoutput.txt -InputObject $testout -append
    Write-Output "--------------------" | Out-File ./_testoutput.txt -append
}
```

It turns out that the **tee** command can send text to a file, but for some odd reason it's unable to *append* to a file. So you have to capture the output in a variable, then append the variable to the file.

Although this result does solve some of my problem, it still doesn't produce a file which *only* contains the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like so:

```
$Error.Clear()
scala -nocompdaemon $script 2>&1 | Tee -FilePath output.txt -Append
$Error >> errors.txt
```

If you clear the global `$Error` collection first, then when you're loop executes it should contain only the errors generated by the scala command.

Answer (score 0):

May be what you're after, try Start/Stop-Transcript
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff687007.aspx
But note that there is an issue with some native executables, here is a work around:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2010/01/04/workaround-for-start-transcript-on-native-processes.aspx